Pages still display when theme is missing
I'm having problems with a custom theme and pages on the front end other than the home page displaying:

There has been a critical error on this website.

This error message is displayed on an error page that includes the site's main navigation in the same style as the rest of the site and the site's logo.
I've tried all the recommended methods for getting error messages to display, i.e.
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

and can't get anything to display.
The weird thing is that only some of the pages were displaying the error initially until I tried changing themes to see if it would fix the broken pages (it did) but then when I switched back to the custom theme again, that's when all the other pages started displaying the same error page too. It's like cached versions of the pages are somehow being displayed.
Just to see what would happen, I removed the custom theme folder altogether, but the pages are still showing the same error page. And in themes.php the theme is still there and can be activated.
How can the theme still be displaying if it's not even in the themes folder anymore? :?
Edit: I can even edit the theme files in WP's theme editor even though the theme folder isn't there. How is that even possible?

WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY will prevent debug messages from being displayed in the browser, but WP_DEBUG_LOG will send them to wp-content/debug.log by default (as long as the webserver user can write to that directory). See Debugging in WordPress for more details.

Yes, I understand that. wp-content is writable, but I don't get the log file.

Does it work if you set something like define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/debug.log' ); instead?

No, it doesn't. At this point I'm actually more interested in how the site can even work when the theme folder isn't present and how I can even edit the theme in the theme editor too.
